# Fatal error: json-glib.h file not found

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm trying to accomplish a simple json query, but havn't been able to get any code to compile because the error is as below:

> fatal error: json-glib.h file not found

It comes up when trying to compile the following line:

```
#include <json-glib.h>
```

I've done a bunch of searching on google and can't find what I've done wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Loren

Edit:

I’m using Tizen studio and developing a wearable app for a Samsung Gear S3.

Comment: Please share here for which Tizen Platform you're developing the app. Also please share information about the device you're developing app for such as mobile or wearable?

Comment: @ShaswatiSaha I posted an edit addressing your questions in the OP.  I’m happy to provide additional information if I can.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're developing app for Samsung Gear S3, you should include headers available for Tizen Version 3.0. For Wearable 3.0, available header for json-glib is as below. You may try using this in your app.

```
#include <json-glib/json-glib.h>
```

The header (`#include <json-glib.h>`) you're trying to use is available till Wearable 2.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
#include <json-glib/json-glib.h>
```