# How to solve a problem of including json-glib.h in a c++ file

Tags: json, ubuntu, glib, apt

I'm trying to compile a c++ file that requires the header json-glib.h and the compilation log says that such header is not found. I'm in ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I've tried executing `dpkg -l '*json-glib*'` to check that i have such file in my system and the result is:

```
||/ Nombre                                       Versión                     Arquitectura                

ii  libjson-glib-1.0-0:amd64                     1.4.2-3                     amd64                     
ii  libjson-glib-1.0-common                      1.4.2-3                     all
```

So next, i executed the command `pkg-config --cflags libjson-glib-1.0` and got:

```
Package libjson-glib-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libjson-glib-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libjson-glib-1.0' found
```

I tried  `pkg-config --cflags json-glib-1.0` , `pkg-config --cflags json-glib`, and `pkg-config --cflags libjson-glib` as well and the result is similar as above.

I also followed the instructions of the answers of [Fatal error: json-glib.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549411/fatal-error-json-glib-h-file-not-found) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297277/make-doesnt-find-an-installed-library/298035#298035 and still i have the problem.

My include in the code is:

```
 #include <json-glib/json-glib.h>
...
```

I will appreciate any help you can give me, Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to install the package `libjson-glib-dev`, after that run `pkg-config --cflags json-glib-1.0`

Answer (score 1):

Same issue... I've resolved with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libjson-glib-dev
```